# Is there any way to create a custom card in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on an educational app and I'm asking if there is any way to create custom card using Flutter like the following picture

[image]

**Edit:** My Code, I did the card with curved image, I stucked in making a red badge with icon, and the white curved container below the image on the card is there any help?

```
    SizedBox(
      width: width * .7,
      height: height * .55,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
          children: [
            Card(
              color: Colors.purple,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(height * .02),
                ),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: width * .65,
                  height: height * .56,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Stack(
                          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
                          children: [
                            ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(height * .01),
                                topRight: Radius.circular(height * .01),
                              ),
                              child: Image.asset(imagePath),
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  color: Colors.amber[800],
                                  height: height * .05,
                                  width: width * .2,
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      lessonNum,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: iconBackgorundColor,
              radius: height * .03,
              child: Icon(
                icon,
                size: height * .03,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: try venture Custom Painter.

Comment: Sure. What did you try, where are you stuck?

Comment: @nvoigt I updated the question with my code and my output

Answer (score 0):

I believe You Can Use Custom Painter,to design any structure you want.

Comment: Or you can use Box Shadow with offset and other properties to Your above card.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).